# MongoDB TTL Collection

Tags: java, mongodb, ttl

I have a collection of Markers that have a 'createdAt' date that mongo will expire every hour for me, I also have a collection of Users where each user has a list of ObjectId to the markers they set, is there any way I can remove the Marker id from the users marker list when MongoDB expires a marker?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [TTL Index - Delete Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-ttl/#delete-operations)

> A background thread in mongod reads the values in the index and removes expired documents from the collection.
>
> When the TTL thread is active, you will see delete operations in the output of db.currentOp() or in the data collected by the database profiler.

There doesn't seem to be any way to hook into the process.

What you could do though is stop keeping list of Markers on the user side and instead keep a user ID in a marker itself (and add appropriate index depending on how will you store the reference and query for it). This way you'll have quick way to retrieve user's Markers and won't need to worry about stale entries in the list at a cost of an additional query.